# The eponymous class of java

Tags: java

Any Java code will always have a class which has the same name as that of the file. The whole designed program resides inside this class. However, in C++ we don't have this provision. What is the rationale behind this approach where the whole code resides inside a class? What extra advantage does this provide? Can we create objects of this class and call the main function of this class as many times as we wish?

Comment: see also: [Why does Java not permit the use of headers as in C++](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/119055/31260)

Comment: @gnat : I beg to differ ,sir. This question basically asks the reason behind including the program code inside a class(let's say the main function ).It also has a part which asks about creation of the objects  for this class.

Comment: [How to handle a question that asks many things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267059/839601)

Comment: So, are you *actually* asking why Java does not allow free functions (functions outside of any class)?

Comment: @5gon12eder : Yes in a way. But ,given by newbie status at java , I am not even sure if there are always restrictions on functions to be inside class.

Comment: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185109/why-java-does-not-allow-function-definitions-to-be-present-outside-of-the-class

Comment: @5gon12eder : Yes , this was helpful but would like to know in detail about the linking process and "mangling" scheme . Could you provide any links for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1:

> What is the rationale behind this approach where the whole code resides inside a class? What extra advantage does this provide?

I'll link to the same link that gnat provided as [a possible duplicate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130398/why-does-a-java-source-file-bear-the-name-of-the-public-class-it-contains) because I think it gives some useful information.  The takeaway being that having each public class inhabit its own file allows for faster compilation.

In addition, one of the practical benefits of the Java way of doing things is that we can actually have multiple `main` functions.  In fact, all of your classes could have a `main` function.  You still typically only have one `main` function in a given project, but I've seen alternative main functions used to:

- Drive unit/integration/regression tests
- Create a version of the program with a limited feature set(could be useful when setting up a 'demo'?)

## Question 2:

> Can we create objects of this class and call the main function of this class as many times as we wish?

Technically, yes you can.  Lets say we have:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

We can then create objects of type `Foo`.  We can further call `main` from that object:

```
Foo obj = new Foo();
obj.main(null);
```

However, you don't typically do this in Java.  `main` is a `static` function, meaning you don't need an object in order to call it.  It would be just as valid to call `Foo.main(null);`.  In the above `obj.main(null);`, the `obj` object is essentially ignored.  The Java compiler, by default, should give you a warning against doing this that looks like this:

> The static method main(String[]) from the type Foo should be accessed in a static way.

Which again, is just telling you to drop the object and to use the *class* to call the static method.

However, to answer your question: you *can* call the static main function as many times as you'd like, just like any other static method.  Just remember that you're not calling the *object's* static main method, you're calling the *class's* static main method - because objects don't have static methods, classes have static methods.